# .htaccess php to html only in root

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I been using .htaccess to change php to html and it works great, but I hit a snag when I forgot that some of my static html pages in subfolders don't appear in the web browser.

Is there a way I can make it so I can only have the root folder uses the .htaccess rule and not the subfolders?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case define your .htaccess rule like this:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?![^/]+/)(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Negative lookahead will prevent sub directory rule implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can specific a rule to work only on current dir. Like:

```
/your/dir/here/.htaccess
```

You .htaccess will be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/here(.*)\.html$ $2.php [L]
```

`$2` mean *get second group*.

**Edit**: alternativaly, you can make a .htaccess on subfolder and disable RewriteEngine.